# Spring Roo - Unknown statement type

Tags: spring-roo

I have this error in my spring roo shell:

```
Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press CTRL+SPACE or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
roo> entity jpa --class ~.domain.SysUserTokenn
Unknown statement type
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\br\com\yazigitravel\eic\domain\SysUserTokenn.java
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA\br\com\yazigitravel\eic\domain\SysUserTokenn.java
Unknown statement type
~.domain.SysUserTokenn roo> Unknown statement type
```

I'm using JDK 1.7 and Spring Roo 1.2.4.RELEASE with a STS IDE.

Comment: What is the code you used?

Comment: A good description of your devel environment is needed: S.O, STS version, etc.